# Connect from web app to Oracle DB docker container

Tags: spring, docker

I'm running on the same host a tomcat container where I've deployed a web application and an oracle DB container. The settings I'm using the following settings to connect from the web app to the oracle DB container:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP of the host>:1521:xe 
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

As I'm exposing the port 1521 to the host, I was expecting to be able to connect to the Oracle DB with no issues, furthermore, I can connect from my laptop to the Oracle DB using DbVisualizer using the settings described above. I've also got into the tomcat container and pinged the host with success.

I know I could link both containers when running the "docker run" command but I was wondering if it could work this way too.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is using docker-compose:

docker-compose.yml

```
version:'3'
services:
  app:
    // if you got a custom dockerfile
    build: . 
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: oracledb
```

The db host into app will "db": 
`spring.datasource.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:db:1521:xe`

To run bought contanier at the same time is: `docker-compose up --build`

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thanks German, I know about docker compose but I thought my setup should work as well.

Comment: Just as a side note, this is not really a docker-compose specific thing. By default, all containers connected to the same `docker network create` network can resolve their ip addresses by the `--name` of the container you want to connect to. There is a way to add an alias as well using `--net-alias`. Under the hood, docker-compose uses the net alias feature to set an alias that matches the service name from the docker-compose file.